# How to write a chart for imagePullSecret from gcr

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to write Helm Charts for our product. The images are stored on GCR private repo. The charts for all components are ready, but I'm trying to write a YAML file in a chart for imagePullSecrets. I've read chart tips from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md#creating-image-pull-secrets),

I also know how to create imagePullSecret with:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry mydockercfg \
        --docker-server "https://eu.gcr.io" \
        --docker-username _json_key \
        --docker-email not@val.id \
        --docker-password=$(cat your_service_account.json)
```

But I don't know how to fill the content of "your_service_account.json" to password of values.yaml of that Chart. It's better I can change the name "your_service_account.json" to update the password of values.yaml.

Currently, My implementation is as follows:

```
$ cat values.yaml
secretName: gcr-json-key-test
imageCredentials:
  registry: us.gcr.io/xxxxx
  username: _json_key
  password:
```

Contents of secrets.yaml:

```
$ cat templates/secrets.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
    labels:
    app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
type: kubernetes.io/dockercfg
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ template "imagePullSecret" . }}
```

Contents of _helpers.tpl:

```
$ cat templates/_helpers.tpl
{{/*
Expand the name of the chart.
*/}}
{{- define "name" -}}
{{- default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
{{/*
Create a default fully qualified app name.
We truncate at 63 chars because some Kubernetes name fields are limited 
to this (by the DNS naming spec).
 */}}
{{- define "fullname" -}}
{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- define "imagePullSecret" }}
{{- printf "{\"auths\": {\"%s\": {\"auth\": \"%s\"}}}" .Values.imageCredentials.registry (printf "%s:%s" .Values.imageCredentials.username .Values.imageCredentials.password | b64enc) | b64enc }}
{{- end }}
```

And then using

```
$ helm install ./secrets --set imageCredentials.password "$(cat ./my_service_account.json)"
```

Will result an error:

> Error: This command needs 1 argument: chart name

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The format of  setting values is: --set <key>=<value>.  Note the "="  Have you tried 

$helm install ./secrets --set imageCredentials.password="$(cat ./my_service_account.json)"

Comment: thanks. I still have problem after correcting my input. For the characters limitation, I put the outputs in the next answer.

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact current error you see?
  Also, what is the format of your_service_account.json?

Answer (score 7):

It can be created and deployed using the following steps:

**Steps:**

1. Create base64 encoded string using your docker_username and docker_password

   ```
   $ echo -n "docker_username:docker_password" | base64
   ZG9rY2VyX3VzZXI6ZG9ja2VyX3Bhc3N3b3Jk
   ```
2. Place the encoded string obtained in the **Step 1** as value for **auth** key in the following Json and fill the required details.

   ```
   {
     "https://eu.gcr.io":
      { 
        "username":"docker_user",
        "password":"docker_password",
        "email":"docker@gamil.com",
        "auth":"ZG9rY2VyX3VzZXI6ZG9ja2VyX3Bhc3N3b3Jk",
      }
    }
   ```
3. Reduce this **json** into a **string** enclosed by single quote:

   ```
   '{"https://eu.gcr.io":{"username":"docker_user","password":"docker_password","email":"docker@gamil.com","auth":"ZG9rY2VyX3VzZXI6ZG9ja2VyX3Bhc3N3b3Jk"}}'
   ```
4. Create base64 encoded string for the above Json string as follows:

   ```
   $ echo -n '{"https://eu.gcr.io":{"username":"docker_user","password":"docker_password","email":"docker@gamil.com","auth":"ZG9rY2VyX3VzZXI6ZG9ja2VyX3Bhc3N3b3Jk"}}' | base64 
   eyJodHRwczovL2V1Lmdjci5pbyI6eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImRva2Nlcl91c2VyIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJkb2NrZXJfcGFzc3dvcmQiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImRvY2tlckBnYW1pbC5jb20iLCJhdXRoIjoiWkc5clkyVnlYM1Z6WlhJNlpHOWphMlZ5WDNCaGMzTjNiM0prIn19
   ```
5. Create secret.yml in the following format:

   ```
   $ cat templates/secrets.yaml
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Secret
   metadata:
      name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
      labels:
        app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
        chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
        release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
        heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
   type: kubernetes.io/dockercfg
   data:
     .dockercfg: {{ .Values.dockercfg }}
   ```
6. Place the encoded string obtained in **Step 4** in the value.yaml:

   ```
   $ cat values.yaml
   secretName: gcr-json-key-test
   dockercfg:
   ```
7. Install the chart using the following command:

   ```
   $ helm install ./secrets -n release_name --set dockecfg="eyJodHRwczovL2V1Lmdjci5pbyI6eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImRva2Nlcl91c2VyIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJkb2NrZXJfcGFzc3dvcmQiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImRvY2tlckBnYW1pbC5jb20iLCJhdXRoIjoiWkc5clkyVnlYM1Z6WlhJNlpHOWphMlZ5WDNCaGMzTjNiM0prIn19" --debug
   ```

   or store it in a file ( .dockercfg ) and use the following command

   ```
   $ helm install ./secrets -n release_name --set dockecfg="$(cat ./.dockercfg )"
   ```

Hope this will be useful...!! :)

Comment: typo near end: `dockecfg` -> `dockercfg`